# Text plus hiding messages on lock screen

Tags: iphone

How do I keep message from displaying on lock screen with text plus. Can't make adjustments with app or in settings

Comment: Try going to the settings>notifications>text free, and see if there are anything thy says show preview on or off

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings-> Notifications and select the app. Now there is an option "show alerts in lock screen" that you could turn off. Also you could switch from alerts to "none" if you dont want to have alerts at all